# Show/hide Finder, and create new window if none exist via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder, keyboard-maestro

I'd like to create an AppleScript to trigger via key command in Keyboard Maestro that allows me to toggle showing or hiding the Finder window(s) directly. And if when toggling to show the Finder, if there are no existing windows, create one and open it up to my home directory.

The following AppleScript works. However, there seems to be a race condition between activating the finder and detecting if there are any open windows with `if not (window 1 exists)`, hence the `delay 0.5`.

The problem (which I think is a race condition in detecting the presence of an existing Finder window) results in this script frequently creating new Finder windows when one already existed. The `if not (window 1 exists)` doesn't always get it right.

Any thoughts, tweaks, or affirmations that this is just the way it is would be appreciated!

```
tell application "System Events"
    set activeApp to name of application processes whose frontmost is true

    if ((activeApp as string) is equal to "Finder") then
        set visible of process "Finder" to false
    else
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            delay 0.5
            if not (window 1 exists) then
                make new Finder window
                set thePath to POSIX file "/Users/jon"
                set the target of the front Finder window to folder thePath
            end if
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this simpler syntax, it uses only `Finder` terminology

```
tell application "Finder"
    if frontmost then
        set visible of process "Finder" to false
    else
        if (count windows) is 0 then reveal home
        activate
    end if
end tell
```

Edit:

To run a Keyboard Maestro macro, open Keyboard Maestro Editor, select the macro and then select Copy as > Copy UUID from the Edit menu.

Then in AppleScript write

```
tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine" to do script "<Script-UUID>"
```

replacing `<Script-UUID>` with the copied real UUID

Comment: vadian, I'd use `open` in place  of `reveal`, as that would then do as the _code_ in the OP does.

Comment: vadian - after the home window opens, how could I type the following key command: `cmd+ctrl+opt+shift+d`? That's a combo in Keyboard Maestro that positions the window with certain dimensions and in a certain spot on the screen. I've tried using system events and keystroke, but it seems to execute even if reveal home wasn't needed. To clarify, I'd like to only position _new_ windows. If there are more than 0 windows, just show them.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I needed to activate Finder before running the count windows command or I'd get inconsistent window counts. Sometimes it'd be 0 even when there was a window open already. This code is working well for me so far.

```
tell application "Finder"
    if frontmost then
        set visible of process "Finder" to false
    else
        activate
        if (count windows) is 0 then
            open home
            tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine" to do script "<Script-UUID>"
        end if
    end if
end tell
```